# addEventListener "onmouseover" Not Working on Table Cells

Tags: javascript, html, cell, addeventlistener

I have this code. I am using it in Chrome, and the console is not throwing out any errors. See below;

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("slot");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("click", function(){ alert("WOrks"); });
}
```

If I change the code to this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("slot");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("onmouseover", function(){ alert("WOrks"); });
}
```

It does not work at all.

All of the elements in the class "slot" are `<td>` elements. What is wrong with this code?

---

**Solution**: As per the accepted answer, the first parameter in `.addEventListener` should be `mouseover`, not `onmouseover`.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML also. 
It would be better if you can put a fiddle.

Comment: Use `mouseover` not `onmouseover`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your event handler should respond to `mouseover` and not `onmouseover`.

Answer (score 2):

```
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("slot");
 for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function(){ alert("WOrks"); });
}
```

Use mouseover not onmouseover